# IOS simulator problem app only runs when started for the second time..

Tags: ios, simulator

My app runs fine on my physical device (iphone 4), it also runs fine on the IOS simulator, but only after the second time I ty to run it from Xcode.

So the sequence in which things are happening is:

1. IOS simulator closed.
2. I press "ctrl R" in XCode
3. IOS simulator starts, app starts but gets no further then the splash screen (does
   not crash it just sits at the splash screen)
4. I press the stop Button in Xcode (app stops running in Simulator)
5. I Press "ctrl R" again
6. App starts in IOS simulator and runs like a charm..

If I close the IOS simulator reopen open it from finder and run the installed version, it runs without problems.

Two questions,

1. has anyone had a similar experience?
2. am I in trouble when submitting my app to the appStore

Thnx, Sebastian

Comment: What version of Xcode and what version of Mac OS X? I found that working with the simulator from Xcode3.2.5 under Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) was unreliable, and I seem to recall it behaved as you describe. I had to move to Xcode4, which in hindsight has been fine. Gotta move to Xcode4 eventually anyway...

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm Using Version 4.0.1, on OSX 10.6.8

Comment: 4.0.1 was kinda buggy. You might try 4.1 for Snow Leopard, which seems to be the stable release at this point.

Comment: The appstore tells me I'd have to upgrade to Lion, I'm not sure if I want that.

Comment: Nope, there is an Xcode 4.1 kit available for both Snow Leopard and Lion. Two separate kits. You choose. :-) I am using 4.1 at work (Snow Leopard) and 4.1 at home (Lion), form different kits. Download the kit you need via developer.apple.com, not the App Store.

Comment: I just started the download :-) Hope this fixes the problem

Comment: Running Xcode 4.1 now but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away when I removed the majority of my logging messages (I had ton's of them). So either there was an issue with one of the messages or it had to do with the amount of them , hope this helps anyone who experiences the same problems.