# JQM/Phonegap native app stuck at splash screen when run on Iphone simulator from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574347/ios-simulator-problem-app-only-runs-when-started-for-the-second-time) seems to have a similar problem, except mine doesn't work at all, not just on the first try.  Today I installed xcode 4.2/ios simulator 5.0 hoping that would fix the problem, but it hasn't helped.  The app has consistently run on actual devices, but all the developers who own Iphones are out of the office today and the company ipod is in use elsewhere.

I've tried closing both xcode and the ios simulator, changing between 5.0 and 4.3, changing between regular iphone and iphone retina, trying with simulator running first and trying with simulator closed first.  It just sits there on the loading screen.  As far as I know the simulator has never worked, I'm not the one who setup xcode or any of the devices (he doesnt work on Mondays and didn't know how to fix it on Friday anyway).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out adding "localHosts" to ExternalHosts fixed the Simulator, but the simulator doesn't like the ajax call to our services site, so it still isn't working, but now at least we have an acceptable reason for it.  (Devices work correctly, so it isn't that big of a deal)  Hope this helps someone.

If anyone can think of a way for the simulator to work with the reference to external calls I'll transfer the answer to their answer :P.

Answer (score 0):

Like Luke said in a comment to you: **just use JSONP**.

It's not the simulator's fault, that's just how browsers work. They don't allow cross-domain ajax requests. That's why there is a solution to this problem, namely JSONP. In essence, the response must be a regular JSON object that is enclosed in a function call, something like `callback_function({json: 'object'})`.