# Ios phonegap app got stuck

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created a phonegap ios application. After installing it is working fine. But after rebooting the mobile it got stuck on splash screen. I can't describe my question clearly.

Actually my app is working fine on first time but when i am opening it for second time after closing it, it got stuck in splash screen. Please let me khow what other thing you need to know about this question.  Thanks

Comment: This guy has the opposite problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574347/ios-simulator-problem-app-only-runs-when-started-for-the-second-time

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you please help me on this....

Comment: Please suggest me some links where i can find any soulution or such type of solution ...

Comment: I cant give you the solution but i can suggest you to check the page using alert. I think some function of your app is not working ...

Comment: Did you check if the app is crashing second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue (stuck on splash screen on 2nd app launch) but it only occurred when the device was plugged into the computer / xcode.

Unplugged it & app opened up second time ok.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information here to answer the problem because there are many things that could create this problem.

Your basic problem is that the root of your application is not resolving.

I would look into the JS on your initial page.  Are you saving any information to local storage?  Something is different between the first load and the second.  What data are you saving on the first load that may persist to the second?

Comment: Do not use an answer to post questions and ask additional info. Use the question comments for this.